# can i create a multi dimensional numpy array based on a single dimensional numpy array with a direct numpy method

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence

**suppose I have a NumPy array**.

```
Input = [1,0,2,0,1,0,2]
```

**and I want the output like this**.

```
[[0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]
```

- my output should be **[unique values in input array]-dimensional array**.
- **Example**: in this case, I have 3 unique values (0,1,2), so my output should be a **3-dimensional array**.
- value or array will be decided based on where the particular unique value is present in the input array.
- **Example**: suppose I have an array `[0,2,0]` so my output should be `[[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]`.
- can I achieve this with a **single NumPy function**.

thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code helps you:

```
import numpy as np
# here is your input array
input_array = np.array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2])
# we get all distinct values by converting it to a set
distinct_values = set(input_array)
# now we iterate over input_value for all distinct values
output_array = np.array([
    int(input_value == value) # int(True) == 1, int(False) == 0
    for value in distinct_values
    for input_value in input_array
# the length of the resulting array is len(input_array) * len(distinct_values)
# to get a propper array we reshape it
]).reshape(
    len(distinct_values),  # number of rows
    len(input_array)       # number of columns
)
```

---

```
>> output_array
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```